# What is Port 8008 ? What attack is possible on this port

Tags: networking

What is 8008 Attack and how is it initiated in the system? What are it’s mitigation and  prevention.

Comment: it's a open port, anything can be listening at that port

Comment: Any application can run a service on any port that is not already in use by any other application. Also, ports are per transport protocol, e.g. TCP port 12345 is _not_ the same port as UDP port 12345, SCTP port 12345, DCCP port 12345, etc., and all can simultaneously be in use by various applications, so when you ask about ports, you must specify which transport protocol you mean.

Answer (score 0):

8008 is not a well known port, that means you should not expect the information passed through this port to be structured using a certain protocol.

According to Wikipedia it is **unofficially** an alternative port for HTTP, but again it's not guaranteed at all that this would be used for HTTP messages. A few companies communicate through this port using different protocols, and other than that you can't actually know what is passed through this port.

Regarding possible attacks on this port, you should understand that a port number is **not a vulnerability**, what can be a vulnerability regarding networking attacks is either the data that is passed or the way it was sent (DDOS, unencrypted data, middleman attacks and so on - but not the port number by itself).

It's worth noting that you might won't want to connect to certain ports if they're **not relevant** to your project, as a precautious step. For example, HTTP proxies usually don't connect to ports other than the well known HTTP and HTTPS ports (80 and 443, respectively) because they can't trust the messages they're delivering to be actually HTTP messages, and not be used for malicious purposes that would hurt the proxy's servers.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably Fortigate Web Filter. A possible attack can be built upon that information. [You can see more here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/fortinet/comments/f2of3l/fortigate_web_filter_on_tcp_8008_and_8010/)